# How much ram should consume Mysql from 16BG server

Tags: 20.04, mysql

Imagine we have dedicated Mysql server where whole amount of RAM is 16GB and database contains some tables which have more that 100mil rows. How much should be for system Ubuntu 20 and for database itself?

Comment: Whatever works for you.  It is impossible to answer this based on the info you provide: Something as simple as the storage engine is important for this question. But there is so much more. You need to perform an analysis yourself and come up with ideal settings for mysql.   Oh mysql starts out with 512Mb in memory.

Comment: What are you asking? You gave the total system RAM as 16GB. Now you're asking for the RAM for the system compared to the database. Well, the minimum Ubuntu server is 1GB at https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/installation . So it would be wise to give the rest to the database for performance, so apparently according to your question, 15GB. What are you trying to figure out?

Comment: I am not sure if ram for system does not limit the database although it has 15GB.

Comment: You didn't mention the columns, indices, and access patterns. You might find better answers at https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bmysql%5d%20RAM&searchOn=3

Comment: RAM usage is wholly dependent on the data that is read into the cache. Without knowing what you have 100-million rows of, and how it will be queried, it will be pretty much impossible to calculate an expected amount of RAM usage 